# HA in MySQL Community Edition deployed on Azure VM

Tags: mysql, azure

How can we use MySQL Community Edition as Highly Available (HA) and Fault-Tolerant on Azure Virtual Machine? I am not able to use Azure PaaS service as it is currently in Preview Mode.

Answer (score 0):

> How can we use MySQL Community Edition as Highly Available (HA) and
>   Fault-Tolerant on Azure Virtual Machine?

You can use Azure **load balancer** and **Azure VMs** to deploy a Mysql replication environment with one master and one slave server(support GTID based replication).

Deploys 2 VMs in an Azure Vnet, in the same availability set, and each has 2 data disks striped into Raid0. Then deploy a load balancer in front of the 2 VMs.

Here a [template](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/mysql-replication) about mysql replication, please refer to it.

Also here a example about use load balanced sets to clusterize Mysql on Linux, please refer to [it](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/virtual-machines/linux/classic/mysql-cluster.md).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Just checking in to see if the information provided was helpful. Please let me know if you would like further assistance.